# How to redirect onKeyPress using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser

I am trying to redirect the user when they try to open the developer's console. I want to be able to do this in all major browsers.

Comment: Usage in browsers menu!!! Am disable devtools with key

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot disable the developer tools via your website. and even if you find a way, that is not an intended feature.

Comment: or turn on devtools from browsers menu, a can do turn off chrome, if user used chrome, but menu users, used chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in any conventional browsers. It goes against the idea of those tools to be able to disable them with code from a website.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your question:

It is possible to redirect onKeyPress but most browsers will block this.

Javascript tutorial can be found on:

```
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/JS/javascript.html
```

The English dictionary can be found at:

```
http://dictionary.reference.com/
```

StackOverflow tags explained:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging
```

I don't think i can help you any further.

Comment: While amusing, this is not an answer to the question - whatever that question is, I can't figure it out either. (Also, no small irony in the fact that you failed to capitalize "I" in the last line)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Hehe, spelling error. And thank you for pointing out the fact that this is not an answer. I fixed that issue.